# Winapi dialog broken on windows xp

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a game that on startup shows dialog to pick language. Everything works on windows 7/8 but not on windows xp (or if I set compatibility mode to windows xp sp 3). Controls are shifted down and window can't be moved, close button don't work.

[image: On left good dialog, on right broken on windows xp]

I create dialog like this:

```
dialog_state = 0;
    HWND hwnd = CreateDialog(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, PickLanguageDialogProc);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    MSG aMsg = {};
    while(dialog_state == 0 && GetMessage(&aMsg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if(!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &aMsg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&aMsg);
            DispatchMessage(&aMsg);
        }
    }
```

Message handler:

```
static INT_PTR CALLBACK PickLanguageDialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        // snip, fill list box
        return TRUE;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwndDlg);
        return TRUE;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        dialog_state = 2;
        return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        // snip
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwndDlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Dialog code:

```
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 148, 146
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Select language"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,91,125,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,7,125,50,14
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST2,7,29,134,93,LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Select language (can be changed in options later):",IDC_STATIC,7,7,134,21
END
```

Compiled on window 8 64bit with Visual Studio 2008. App is 32 bit. Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: It looks like someone adds an empty menu in XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
return DefWindowProc(hwndDlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

to

```
return FALSE;
```

fix my problem.
Looks like dialog box need different handling then normal window.

Comment: They [sort of do](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/07/55619.aspx) indeed.